# Converting seq<string> to string[] in F#

Tags: string, f#

The example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144274/string-replace-utility-conversion-from-python-to-f) has an example

```
open System.IO

let lines = 
  File.ReadAllLines("tclscript.do")
  |> Seq.map (fun line ->
      let newLine = line.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}")
      newLine )

File.WriteAllLines("tclscript.txt", lines)
```

that gives an error when compilation.

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    string []    
but here has type
    seq<string>
```

How to convert seq to string[] to remove this error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on Jaime's answer, since `ReadAllLines()` returns an array, just use `Array.map` instead of `Seq.map`

```
open System.IO

let lines = 
  File.ReadAllLines("tclscript.do")
  |> Array.map (fun line ->
      let newLine = line.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}")
      newLine )

File.WriteAllLines("tclscript.txt", lines)
```

Comment: +1 - This approach probably performs somewhat better than an Array -> Seq -> Array mapping.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
File.WriteAllLines("tclscript.txt", Seq.toArray lines)
```

or alternatively just attach

```
|> Seq.toArray
```

after the Seq.map call.

(Also note that in .NET 4, there is an overload of WriteAllLines that does take a Seq)

Comment: Or you can use `Array.ofSeq` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer sequence expressions over higher-order functions, unless you're piping the output through a series of functions. It's usually cleaner and more readable.

```
let lines = [| for line in File.ReadAllLines("tclscript.do") -> line.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}") |]
File.WriteAllLines("tclscript.txt", lines)
```

#### With regex replacement

```
let lines = 
  let re = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"#(\d+)")
  [|for line in File.ReadAllLines("tclscript.do") ->
      re.Replace(line.Replace("{", "{{").Replace("}", "}}"), "$1", 1)|]
File.WriteAllLines("tclscript.txt", lines)
```

Comment: Well, your comment disappeared, but I added the regex replacement you requested.